# Blazor Custom Multiselect Dropdown Component Webassembly

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm tired to search on web a solution for this. Basicly i am using InputBase to extend the normal inputbox to a custom component. For single selection in  its ok, but turns complicate when i have mutiple selection "select multiple="multiple""

So here is the code:

File: XDropDownMultiSelect.razor

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions

@typeparam T
@inherits InputBase<T>

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label))
{
    <label class="form-label">@Label</label>
}


<select @bind="CurrentValue" class="form-control select2 @CssClass" id="@Id" @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" multiple>

    @if (DropdownValues != null)
    {
        foreach (var cursor in DropdownValues)
        {
            <option value="@cursor.Key">@cursor.Value</option>
        }
    }
</select>

@code {
    [Inject] public IJSRuntime _js { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<T>> ValidationFor { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool ShowDefaultOption { get; set; } = true;
    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, string> DropdownValues { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Selected { get; set; }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out T result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            result = (T)(object)value;
            validationErrorMessage = null;

            return true;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string[]))
        {
            result = (T)(object)(new string[] { value });
            validationErrorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Guid))
        {
            Guid.TryParse(value, out var parsedValue);
            result = (T)(object)parsedValue;
            validationErrorMessage = null;

            return true;
        }
        else if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            try
            {
                result = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
                validationErrorMessage = null;

                return true;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                result = default;
                validationErrorMessage = $"The {FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field is not valid.";

                return false;
            }
        }


        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{GetType()} does not support the type '{typeof(T)}'.");
    }
}
```

I use "CurrentValue" instead of "CurrentValueAsString" because is an array no string, and if i set CurrentValueAsString will have a render json problem...

Now i call by simple:

```
 <XDropDownMultiSelect @bind-Value="usersSelected" Id="test" DropdownValues="usersAll" />

@code{
 public string[] usersSelected { get; set; } = new [] { "user1" };
 public string[] usersAll{ get; set; } = new [] { "user1", "user2", "user3" };
```

Its working, but dosen´t bind the new selection values to my selectValues object.

Answer (score 0):

i found how to use CurrentValueAsString

```
 protected override string FormatValueAsString(T? value)
    {
      
        if( value != null)
        {
                return value.ToJson(); //this is extension my to convert any object to json format.
        }
       
        return base.FormatValueAsString(value);
    }
```

But this not update the source model with new selections.